# The code is not running correctly, It is always exiting on the if statement

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.println("Usage: java SkipJack <key> <plaintext>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    BigInteger MASK = new BigInteger("FF", 16);
    BigInteger k = new BigInteger(args[0],16);
    long message = Long.valueOf(args[1]);

    int[] key = new int[10];
    for(int i=0,j=9; i<10; ++i,--j){
        key[j]= k.shiftRight(i*8).and(MASK).shortValue();
    }

    System.out.printf("%016x%n",SkipJack.Encrypt(key,message));
}
```

It's always exiting in the if statement. What do you think is the problem.
P.S: I'm New to Java

Comment: `args` doesn't contains exactly 2 elements

Comment: Did you try using the debugger? You will see that it is an awesome tool !

Comment: What parameters do you pass on the command line? have you tried printing the length of args before exiting?

Answer (score 0):

On your command line, just do `java MyClass 1 2` where 1 should be your key and 2 should be your plaintext. MyClass is your file/class name.

Comment: remove the comma